# Anyone know a game with yellow and blue ducks?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember having a game years ago (it would have been made around 2006-2013) in which there were two players. One player had yellow ducks, and the other had blue. The ducks were 3D, shaped like rubber ducks, only smaller. As far as I can remember, the goal was to get all your ducks across a swamp or pond before the other player did. The board had little oval shaped spaces that I think were indented, so as to fit the bottoms of the ducks in them. I remember that there were lots of ducks, because they ended up all over the house, and I remember that they were small (smaller than a typical rubber duck) at about ¾ inches to 1 inch long. The game was intended for ages around 4-9, so younger kids. Does anyone have any ideas as to what this game is?

Comment: Do you have any more detail as to the rules of movement or anything?  With the description given so far it could just as well have been a themed version of chinese checkers.

Comment: Do you know for what age group the game was designed?

Comment: @JMoravitz: Unfortunately, these are about all the details I can remember. Come to think of it, I do remember something about having yellow and blue paths for the ducks, and multiple starting points, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this game is “Duck Duck 1 - 2 - 3” This game sounds very similar to the game plot and has the blue and yellow ducks[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's it!! Wow, looking at the pictures on [Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41087/duck-duck-1-2-3) brings back memories of the spinner and all the little drawings. I'd forgotten that the holes for the ducks were in the mama ducks' backs, not in the board. Here's a ✓ for you!

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a BoardGameGeek entry, but [this game](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265341029560) for sale on ebay appears to match your description.

It is called "Like Ducks to Water". Specifically, the second image show the indents in the game board meant to receive the ducks:

[image: Like Ducks to Water board game]

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I forgot to mention in my question that the ducks were 3D, like rubber ducks (I edited my question, so that it says so now). But maybe there is an edition of this game that has 3D ducks? Except for that one difference, your game looks _very_ much like it would fit the description in the question.

Comment: UPDATE: I think the game I asked about had a different name.